# I need to hold a value after jboss ran. And I need to use before tomcat starts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss

In my project, I am using `jboss 4.0` and `tomcat 6.0` servers,
and have a `Defaultconstant.java` file which is not a servlet class (i.e Separate entity class)

Values of DefaultConstant.java are stored as static variables and written in static block.

When i starts my jboss server, `Defaultconstant.java` file is getting loaded with all required values and I'm storing it in a map.

When i run my `tomcat` server.
Same file is gets loaded for second time and **it creates another map for storing the Tomcat initialised values.

My Required output is:
I need to hold those map values and should not allow the map to reload once again during tomcat startup.

Answer (score 0):

Use a System property to define a path where `Defaultconstant` can save/load it's data.

Depending on how `Defaultconstant` works, you can either save the data when it doesn't change anymore or you can use a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to notify the class when the app server is shut down.

**EDIT** Java offers no simple way to share data between processes. So when Tomcat starts, you need a way to tell the JBoss server "hey, I also need the values". There are several options:

1. You can save the values to a file from JBoss and read the file in Tomcat. That will give you a *copy* of the values (-> doesn't help if you want to be able to pass changes from Tomcat back to JBoss).
2. Create a web service in JBoss that Tomcat uses during startup to ask for the values.
3. Store the values in a database and configure the same database connector for both web servers. That way, `Defaultconstant` can read and write the values to the same shared storage.

Comment: DafaultConstant is not a servlet class,and i need hold the temp map value.it is possible @aaron Digulla

Comment: @Ramakrishnan: Does not compute. Need more input.

Comment: You can't share map values between processes directly. See my edits for some workarounds.

Comment: if i m using system property. system property it represent  m/y in jvm. here case jboss and tomcat using diff jvm.

Comment: Use the same system property in both systems with the same value: A file that they both should read and then put the shared information into that file.